# PhpStorm is generating weird whitespaces

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, psr-2

When using PhpStorm on Ubuntu - I think I didn't have this problem under OS X - and copy some text, than PhpStorm somehow adds whitespaces to the line. I can see this, because I've got `phpcs` installed which tells me that `x` whitespaces are found at the end of line. I already set in the settings that PhpStorm should remove unnecessary whitespaces when saving, but I don't know why it generates it to begin with.

The same goes, when I'm extending a class with auto completion for example:
`class Foo extends Bar{whitespace}` PhpStorm would now add an unneeded whitespace after the `Bar` and I have to remove it manually all the time. Same goes for importing classes (also when extending), PhpStorm always puts them directly under the `namespace` but I want it to have one line inbetween, because of `PSR-2`. Any ideas?

Comment: Whitespace added when you complete the item via code completion is normal behaviour -- I do have the same for `class Foo extends Bar{whitespace}` case. For me it's expected behaviour (in this particular case) -- allows you to enter `implements` or `{` without the need to type ` ` character; and if you type such stuff on separate line -- space will be trimmed on Save. No real idea about adding spaces on copy -- where it's added -- at the end or in the front? Try changing "Reformat on Paste" option behaviour (hint: Settings screen has a search box).

Comment: Yeah, but when I write `implements` I add the whitespace anyway, and since I use `PSR-2` my brackets come on a new line so it is rather useless :p But thanks! I already set the settings so I have a space between `namespace` and `use`